# Using gettext with content from database in phoenix app?

Tags: translation, phoenix-framework, gettext

I'm trying to use [Gettext and domains](https://hexdocs.pm/gettext/Gettext.html#module-domains) in a phoenix app to translate "materials" (wood, wool, cotton, kapok...).
Materials come from a database.

This works:

```
<%= MyApp.Gettext.dgettext "materials", "cotton" %>
```

But this does not:

```
<%= MyApp.Gettext.dgettext "materials", "#{material.name}" %>
```

I'm trying to add the translation to a template

```
<%= for material <- @materials do %>
  <td><%= AmazingApp.Gettext.dgettext "materials", "#{material.name}" %></td>
<% end %>
```

How can one go about translating in this situation?

Comment: Note that if one just wants dynamic translation based on a variable (instead of an explicit string), `dgettext` is not necessary. Just as shown in the documentation excerpt below, `Gettext.gettext` can already do the job. The "dynamic" part about `dgettext` is just that it allows you to specify a particular subdomain, so I'd consider the naming to be slightly misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Gettext.dgettext/3` for this:

```
<%= Gettext.dgettext(MyApp.Gettext, "materials", material.name) %>
```

From the [documentation](https://github.com/elixir-lang/gettext/blob/399220f54a29232d49514d8644ab07a247e31e56/lib/gettext/compiler.ex#L234):

> Dynamic translations should be avoided as they limit Gettext's
>   ability to extract translations from your source code. If you are
>   sure you need dynamic lookup, you can use the functions in the Gettext
>   module:
>
> ```
> string = "hello world"
> Gettext.gettext(#{inspect(gettext_module)}, string)
> ```

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, and it doesn't work. :(

Comment: You're calling `Gettext.dgettext` or `MyApp.Gettext.dgettext`?

Comment: Facepalm. I tried with MyApp.Gettext, and that didn't work. But of course it was under MyAppWeb.Gettext.

Comment: I don't get the difference between <%= Gettext.dgettext(MyAppWeb.Gettext, "materials", material.name) %> and <%= AmazingApp.Gettext.dgettext "materials", "#{material.name}" %>, but it works. :D

Comment: The difference is that `MyAppWeb.Gettext.gettext/2` is a macro, while `Gettext.dgettext/3` is a function. Thus `Gettext.dgettext/3` can accept string variables, not only string literals.